# Android VpnService protect socket that's stored in native code?

Tags: java, android, c, sockets, android-vpn-service

I'm writing a VPN application and the socket used for the VPN Connection is handled in my native C code, not in java. How do I use `VpnService.protect()` on that socket? I noticed that it has a `VpnService.protect(int)` overload, could I return the int that `socket` returns from the native code to Java and protect it that way?

**Example**

```
// Native Code
int socket;

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_my_package_Class_initializeSocket
(
    JNIEnv *env,
    jobject jobj
) {
    socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    // . . . Handler other socket preparations 

    return (jint)socket;
}
```

---

```
// Java Code
public native int initializeSocket();

. . . 

int socket = initializeSocket();
this.protect(socket);
```

**Edit**

I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38606036/how-does-android-vpnservice-protect-fd-work) that describes how the `protect` function works, and it looks like it might have a pretty simple implementation in C since it appears it's just using a `setsockopt` call. But I'm also relatively new to C so I can't quite follow how to replicate it.

Comment: i didn't understand what these `VpnService.protect()` methods do. Do they keep the sockets _out_ of the VPN?

Comment: @nandsito read this, it explains what they do: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html#protect(int)

Comment: for your question, i guess you can do like you mentioned. I don't recommend doing it in C (the `setsockopt` stuff) because it would use private APIs (besides being hard as hell). If you wish you can call Java code from C, so you can call `VpnService.protect(int)` directly from C code, improving encapsulation

Comment: @nandsito I can't avoid the socket being in C. Unfortunately, the library I'm using handles the socket and it's written in C. I do have access to the socket though.

Comment: sorry, i made an amendment to my comment. It's ok to open socket in C, but i wouldn't do the `setsockopt` call. I'd either call `VpnService.protect(int)` in Java after the JNI invocation or call `VpnService.protect(int)` directly in JNI

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I simply wanted verification that my processes was valid, after completing more testing I've verified that it works.

**Example**

```c
// Native Code
int socket;

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_my_package_Class_initializeSocket
(
    JNIEnv *env,
    jobject jobj
) {
     socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    // . . . Handle other socket preparations 
        
    return (jint)socket;
}
```

```java
// Java Code
public native int initializeSocket();
    
// . . . 

int socket = initializeSocket();
this.protect(socket);
```